# Difference in implementation between clojure.core conj and clojure.core.into

Tags: performance, clojure, clojure-core

What is the difference in terms of efficiency and under-the-hood details

between
`(apply conj [0][1])` and `(into [0][1])`?

Using the `time` function it seems that `apply conj` is faster, but is there a price? and what is it?

Comment: could you please provide your benchmarks? It could happen, that the time difference is irrelevant, since you're benchmarking on some short collections for example. For long vectors `into` should be significantly faster, since it uses transient sequences, according to it's source. For the short ones conj could be a bit faster since it doesn't use any additional machinery, but for `clojure.lang.RT/conj`.

Comment: @leetwinski I timed the functions again and this time I got opposite results, leaving me a little puzzled. What is the actual difference between the two methods? What is preferable when? And you seem to be right at least about long vectors, into is about twice as fast joining two vectors of a size 100 each than using apply conj. So that leaves the question only regarding small vectors, which is in fact preferable?

Comment: `time` is not suitable for benchmarking small things. Check out https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium/

Comment: One question you could ask yourself: "If `(apply conj xs ys)` were better than `(into xs ys)`, why would anyone ever use `into` for anything? Why would `into` even be defined?"

Comment: @amalloy `into` could be better simply because it's one word. Since the implementation of `into` is different, that aroused the question "why is into not implemented with `apply conj`"?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `into` function is generally preferable to `apply conj` in Clojure due to the following reasons:

- Performance: `into` is usually faster than `apply conj`. The `into`
  function is implemented in a way that allows for optimized, efficient
  concatenation of collections. On the other hand, `apply conj` involves
  using `conj` repeatedly with variadic arguments, which can be less
  performant.
- Simplicity & Readability: `into` provides a simpler and more concise
  way to concatenate collections. It takes care of the concatenation
  internally without requiring explicit iteration or multiple function
  calls. Using into makes the code more readable and expressive. It
  clearly communicates the intention of concatenating or merging
  collections, improving the overall code clarity.
- Flexibility: `into` supports merging of collections, not just
  concatenation. It can merge collections of different types or with
  conflicting keys, providing more flexibility in combining data
  structures.

That being said, there may be specific cases where `apply conj` is more suitable, such as when you need to dynamically pass in collection elements as variadic arguments. However, for most general cases, the `into` function is the preferred way to concatenate or merge collections in Clojure.